# No stdout logging output in ROS2 using launch

Tags: ros, ros2, roslaunch, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am unable to see any logging output from stdout when using `ros2 launch`, and I need some help figuring out what's going on / if this is expected. For example this cpp file:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("a_test_node");

  RCLCPP_DEBUG(node->get_logger(), "test log debug");
  RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "test log info");
  RCLCPP_WARN(node->get_logger(), "test log warn");
  RCLCPP_ERROR(node->get_logger(), "test log error");

  rclcpp::spin(node);

  return 0;
}
```

and this launch file:

```
import launch
import launch_ros.actions

def generate_launch_description():
    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='test_pkg',
            node_executable='test_node',
            node_name='test_node',
            output={
                'stdout': 'screen',
                'stderr': 'screen',
            }
        ),
    ])
```

only outputs:

```
jlangsfeld@swri-jlangsfeld-thinkpad-T560:~/Workspaces/ros2$ ros2 launch test_pkg log_test.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/jlangsfeld/.ros/log/2019-09-11-13-45-19-657412-swri-jlangsfeld-thinkpad-T560-18153
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [test_node-1]: process started with pid [18163]
[test_node-1] [WARN] [test_node]: test log warn
[test_node-1] [ERROR] [test_node]: test log error
```

I've tried other `output` options too with no luck. For example, using `own_log` for both stdout and stderr means separate log files are created but the stdout one always is completely empty. Any thoughts / suggestions?

Thanks,
Josh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332829/no-stdout-logging-output-in-ros2-using-launch/) by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 971 on 2019-09-11

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-09-11**:
can you try `output="screen"` without the json? That's what I usually do

ex. https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/master/nav2_bringup/launch/nav2_navigation_launch.py#L81

I see the warn and error, but not info, perhaps because you didnt set to screen in general

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2019-09-11**:
Yes, I've tried the single string, which should just be a shortcut for setting both stdout and stderr directly. Are you saying you don't see info outputs either when you run launch files?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-09-11**:
No, I do see them with just the simple string

**Comment by [942951641@qq.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/38911/942951641@qq.com/) on 2021-06-22**:
in foxy, log can output to ~/.ros/log.

but i found there is a delay time to log file than screen,
i found log file will increase 4096kb every time, so is it flush when buffer is fulled ?

how to set immedialy output every line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This turned out to be connected with the known issue of subprocesses from launch having their stdout streams buffered (https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/188). There is a `emulate_tty` flag that [has recently been added](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/0f81d987039420036a7153c622b075c993ff1558/launch/launch/actions/execute_process.py#L178) to the `ExecuteProcess` action that defaults to `False`. Setting it to `True` in my launch file (through the `Node` action constructor) fixes the problem. Eventually it may default to `True`. (https://github.com/ros2/launch/pull/286)

---

Originally posted by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) with karma: 971 on 2019-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khassanov](https://answers.ros.org/users/32429/khassanov/) on 2019-10-10**:
Could you share your snippet reaches `emulate_tty`, please?

**Comment by [mvoellmy](https://answers.ros.org/users/50270/mvoellmy/) on 2019-12-13**:
I added the `emulate_tty=True` flag here and the outputs worked for me again.

```
Node(
    package='package_name',
    node_executable='package_exec',
    output='screen',
    emulate_tty=True,
    arguments=[('__log_level:=debug')]
)
```

**Comment by [MrCheesecake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44078/mrcheesecake/) on 2020-07-15**:
Does this work with Dashing or only newer versions? 
I'm getting: `[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'emulate_tty'`

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2020-07-16**:
The keyword was added during Eloquent development. But as of Foxy, this problem should be gone because all logging now comes out on stderr which won't buffer output.

**Comment by [mantangL](https://answers.ros.org/users/61426/mantangl/) on 2020-10-21**:
i have same problem in dashing version.[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'emulate_tty'. how can you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With your example, I **do** see the INFO output, but it comes after terminating the program (e.g SIGINT):

```
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [test_node-1]: process started with pid [18943]
[test_node-1] [WARN] [test_node]: test log warn
[test_node-1] [ERROR] [test_node]: test log error
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[test_node-1] [INFO] [test_node]: test log info
```

It's possible there's some buffer funny-business happening in [launch](https://github.com/ros2/launch). It might be worth opening a issue describing the problem.

I wouldn't expect you to be able to see the DEBUG log, without setting the verbosity level accordingly.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2019-09-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2019-09-13**:
I never noticed but the same thing is happening for me too. I'll go ahead and open an issue then.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the following to set the buffering policy to line buffering:

```
stdbuf -o L ros2 launch pkg pkg.launch.py
```

I would personally prefer this over setting an option in the launch file since it gives you some flexibility without having to modify the launch file.

---

Originally posted by [mschickler](https://answers.ros.org/users/48984/mschickler/) with karma: 95 on 2019-11-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aravind](https://answers.ros.org/users/19767/aravind/) on 2020-08-10**:
This worked for me. I would prefer that the default is set to line buffering since I think that is what the majority of users expect when printing output to screen. If not, how can I set the default to be line buffered?

**Comment by [ntrlmt](https://answers.ros.org/users/69131/ntrlmt/) on 2021-02-01**:
I had same problem in dashing version.
I added the **prefix=['stdbuf -o L']** to Node. This worked for me.

```
Node(
    package='package_name',
    node_executable='package_exec',
    prefix=['stdbuf -o L'],
    output='screen'
)
```

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2021-02-19**:
@ntrimt it looks that it doesn't work in Dashing in Windows 10. I'm getting a traceback.

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2021-12-12**:
@ntrlmt answer worked for me ROS2 foxy, thanks